# Android. Как сохранить логи приложения в отдельный файл

Tags: java, android, логирование

В процессе работы я заношу записи в лог так: `Log.d(TAG, "сообщение")`.

Мне хотелось-бы получить лог-файл только с моими сообщениями.

На текущий момент у меня реализован механизм перехвата фатальной ошибки:
Как здесь описано: http://forum.startandroid.ru/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=1781

```
//В классе приложения
static{
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new KuemExceptionHandler());
}
...
//onCreate приложения
Logger.init(app, "login@domen.ru");
...
public class KuemExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler 
{
  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler;
  public KuemExceptionHandler() {
    //Запоминаем старый обработчик
    oldHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
  }

  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
    //Какая-то страшная ОШИБКА!!
    // Заносим в ЛОГ и передаем!!
    Logger.log(throwable);
    //Выводим активность - окно с ошибкой! - не работает в Андроид 8
    Logger.sendError(true);

    if (oldHandler != null)
        oldHandler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
   }
}
```

Могу я в этом обработчике как-то со своим логом работать?